# How to properly set up multiple qlistview with a Model to work like a columnview

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, pyside, qlistview

We develop some kind of Filebrowser in pyside. 
There will be a fixed depth of Data stored in the Model so we want 4 QListLiews to work like a columnview. Our Model is inherited from QAbstractItemModel an has some kind of a tree structure. Now we wonder,what is the correct way to set the Model to the views. Do we have to connect every listviews clicked signal to a method that sets the model in the next qlistview?

here is a screenshot of what we are doing:
[image]

Comment: And you don't want to use [`QColumnView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcolumnview.html#details)?

Comment: Right because we want a fixed count of columns. Furthermore we want to change some button States on specific column clicks. I don't think that's possible with qcolumnview